# How to get each one of the object in four levels nesting Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I create an Object that includes 3 Objects, one of which includes three Objects, and I want to get each one of them to set the value.

And I do not know whether the type of object to divide, it seems all are Object.

I try to do like this, traverse the first time to recognize the Object and the Array, then traverse twice and the third time in depart, but the console shows an error.

>Cannot set property 'www.google.com' of undefined 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'www.google.com ' of undefined 
    at eval (userscript.html?name=
    at Array.forEach ()

The original script excludes the four levels nesting Object [The browser search tool](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397040-%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/code)

```
    Object.keys(iconsData).forEach(function(value1) {

        if(iconsData[value1].constructor === Array){
            iconsData[value1].forEach(function (value2) {
                console.log('typeArray--'+iconsData[value1].constructor)
                value2.host.forEach(function(host) {
                    iconsData.hostCustomMap[host] = value2.custom     // The console shows an Error maybe here
                })
            })
        } else if (iconsData[value1].constructor === Object) {
            Object.keys(iconsData[value1]).forEach(function (value2) {
                console.log('typeObject--'+iconsData[value1].constructor)
                iconsData[value1][value2].forEach(function (value3) {
                    value3.host.forEach(function(host){
                        iconsData.hostCustomMap[host] = value3.custom
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    })
```

The following code includes the nesting Object.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var keyword = {
        beforePopup: function (popup) {
            var text = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
            GM_setValue('search', text);
            popup(text);
        },
        beforeCustom: function (custom) {
            var text = GM_getValue('search');
            GM_setValue('search', '');
            custom(text);
        },

    };

var iconsData = {
    iconArraya: {
        Arraya: [
            {
                name: 'Google',
                image:'https://i.ibb.co/R9HMTyR/1-5.png',
                host: ['www.google.com'],
                popup: function (text) {
                open('https://search.google.com/live?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(text));
                }
            }
        ],
        Arrayb: [
            {
                name: 'Bing',
                image: 'https://i.ibb.co/pwkLTFc/1.png',
                host: ['www.bing.com'],
                popup: function (text) {
                open('https://www.bing.com/live?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(text)');
                }
            }
        ],
        Arrayc: [
            {
                name: 'Youtube',
                image:'https://i.ibb.co/FWVJ3Kf/1-2.png',
                host: ['www.youtube.com'],
                popup: function (text) {
                open('https://www.youtube.com/live?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(text)');
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    iconArrayb: [
        {
            name: 'open',
            image:'https://i.ibb.co/fxpm6Wc/image.png',
            host: [''],
            popup: function (text) {
                open(encodeURIComponent(text));
            }
        }
    ],
    iconArrayc: [
        {
            name: 'copy',
            image:'https://i.ibb.co/PQ5xM2R/2-1.png',
            host: [''],
            popup: function (text) {
                document.execCommand('copy', false, null))
            }
        }
    ],
    hostCustomMap: {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot set property 'www.google.com' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'www.google.com ' of undefined

The error is thrown because hostCustomMap is not a property of iconsData.

In your code you set a variable named hostCustomMap at the end, this should be a property of the object iconsData. Like in the original script.

Like this:

```
var iconsData = {
    iconArraya: ...,
    iconArrayb: ...,
    iconArrayc: ...,
    iconArrayD: ...,
    hostCustomMap: {}
}
```

Not this:

```
var iconsData = {
    iconArraya: ...,
    iconArrayb: ...,
    iconArrayc: ...,
    iconArrayD: ...
}

var hostCustomMap = {}
```

Comment: Yeap, I mistake get hostCustomMap out of Object may reduce some trouble, it should put in.